# Show the number of consecutive closed questions, in the automatic flag

Tags: feature-request, flags, automatic-flags

I have noticed that, recently, the automatic flag for consecutive closed question reports just two links, even if the closed questions are more than two. For example, I get the following flag on *Drupal Answers*.

[image: screenshot]

The consecutive closed questions for that user are the following ones. (I am showing the ones closed in the last hour.)

[image: screenshot]

Isn't possible to have the automatic flag showing the number of consecutive closed questions?

Comment: The message doesn’t look helpful at all: the domain name in the link is less important than the number of questions and the time span from the first to the last closed question. You have to check the user profile anyway, that’s the only link you really need there.